# Git push all commits except first to a remote repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

What I'm going to achieve is to push all the commits (my changes) except the first one (initial codebase) to a public repo.

A - B - C - D - E

I'd like to push to a new remote repo only

B - C - D - E

Is it possible?

Comment: I've tried several approaches (without deep understanding of what's really happening), but it didn't help

Comment: Do a `git rebase interactive` remove A then push.

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't do that. The much longer answer is that the resulting repository would be what Git calls a *shallow repository*. Git does have shallow repositories, but you can't create one using `git push`, hence the short answer, "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you would like the project *content* to be on the first revision is what is in B, this is what you can do:

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch B
git commit -m "new first revision" # use a proper comment
git cherry-pick B..E # replicate revisions C, D and E
```

Then `new-branch` has a history like what you are looking forward to.

If you tried removing the first revision with an interactive rebase, expect to get conflicts on all the files that were modified on B coming from A. Say, if A laid out all, or most of the files, then whatever that was *modified* by B will get a conflict (and other conflicts could be expected when applying C, D and E), as the files do not exist when git will try to apply B on the rebase... not the hardest thing to solve, anyway.... but the recipe that I provide skips that problem altogether.

PS

Another way that this can be done with interactive rebase is running:

```
git rebase -i --root
# revision A, the first one, leave it with a pick
# but ask to squash the second one B
# C, D and E, leave them with a pick
# save and exit
# git will stop so you can set the comment that will be left on the first revision,
# if I'm not wrong, and will show you the first and second revision comment
# set the right comment, save and exit
# rebase will continue and you will get a branch like what you are asking for
```

PS2 so the requirement is a little different from what the question infers, I think (read the comments to this answer).

```
git checkout -b --orphan new-branch A
git rm -r * # remove everyhing
git show --summary --pretty= --name-only B | xargs git checkout B --
# that should get back only the files that were modified in B
git commit -m "whatever comment"
git cherry-pick B..E
```

That should work

Comment: Thank you, but if I'm looking at it correctly - with this approach the new branch will have "he project content to be on the first revision is what is in B", so it's actually contains all the project codebase. 
And I'd like to distinguish my changes from everything else. Is that possible?

Comment: So, just to clarify, there is no way to push only changes, without the whole codebase?

Comment: You could..... but tje requirement is a little different from what the question is about. Let me try to give you one way there with an update on my answer.

Comment: oh, my bad... in my understanding "commit = content", but yeah, now I realize they are different terms.

Comment: in git a commit is actually a snapshot of the project contents but normally we refer to the _changes_ applied by those revisions from their parents, depending on the context. In your case, it wasn't clear that you only wanted ro keep the files that were modified in B up to E

Comment: thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately git show ... added back all the files, not only B, so I guess there is no straightforward solution to achieve what I need.

Comment: What I told you to run should run.... unless you modified all those fields in B. What is the output of `git show --summary --name-only --pretty= B`. Is it a long list of files?